# DEM coordinates do not align other data layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, dem

I recently downloaded Original Product Resolution (OPR) Digital Elevation Model (DEM) data for some analysis. The DEM does not align with any of the other data sets I have for the area.

I have attached a screenshot of the DEM (NAD_1983_2011_Contiguous_USA_Albers) overlaying on an aerial photo (NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N), and the yellow line indicates the discrepancy. I am using ArcMap 10.7.1 and the projection is set as NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N.

How can I rectify this problem?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a classic NAD27  - NAD83 datum problem.  Did you do a define projection or reproject and of these data?   Have you fussed with the transformations in ArcMap?

Comment: Would reprojection hill shade be your suggestion? The Datums are set NAD 1983(2011) and NAD 1983, how can I change one to the other?